# Multiple D3 charts on one page with data binding

Tags: d3.js

I would like to have a JSON data structure that contains time series data for multiple charts (one or more lines per chart) and have this data bound dynamically to D3 so that I only need to specify the template for a single chart and then D3 handles creating the entire grid of charts for me according to some layout that I specify. When the underlying data structure is updated, series automatically get  added or removed from existing charts or whole charts get added or removed.

I've seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5987480) that describes how to place multiple charts on a single page, but in the example code has to be written separately for each chart, whereas I am trying to create multiple charts dynamically.

Comment: I would suggest creating a reusable chart constructor: http://ejb.github.io/2017/08/09/a-better-way-to-structure-d3-code-es6-version.html. Then, nest the data so different keys can be passed to a `forEach()` loop creating (and destroying upon each call to draw) the chart(s).

Comment: Thanks Ryan, this worked. I will post an example soon.